# 'Core Dumped' while opening Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text, segmentation-fault

I am getting `4xxx Bus error (core dumped)` while trying to open Sublime Text by using this command

```
/usr/lib/sublime-text-2/sublime_text --class=sublime-text-2 "$@" .
```

It was working perfectly until yesterday. Any remedy for this? Do I need to reinstall Sublime?

Comment: I have the same issue(Arch). Try to downgrade `glibc` package, since gdb gives me `0xb7ff6b57 in memset () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2`(`ld-linux.so.2` refers to `ld-2.17.so` which is from `glibc` package). Unfortunately, I have a lot of dependencies from `glibc-17`, so, I can't downgrade it right now.

Comment: OK, downgrading from `glibc-2.17-6` to `glibc-2.17-2` doesn't solve the problem, and I can't downgrade more because of dependencies. Just replacing `ld-2.17.so` with `ld-2.16.so` doesn't work too.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with `SublimeCodeIntel` package. Just move(or remove) it outside of `Packages` folder:

```
mv <path to sublime-text>/Packages/SublimeCodeIntel ~/
```

Then run Sublime Text and re-install `SublimeCodeIntel` from `PackageControl`:

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> -> *Package Control: Install Package* -> *SublimeCodeIntel*.

Comment: thanks @soon..for a minute I thought I lost my sublime text

Comment: @ManojGumber, Glad it helped :)

Comment: Actually, reinstalling didn't work at all for me, but at least it helped me to identify what was the source of the problem. I just uninstalled SublimeCodeIntel and goodbye segmentation faults:)